# Ending: accusative or not?

Tags: grammatical-case, accusative

I have to complete the following sentence:

> Wir machen die Aufgabe wider unser_ Willen.

I would write 'unsere' (accusative plural), instead in the solution they write 'unseren'?

Why? Is it an error?

Comment: The use of _unser_ relates to _Willen_ so _unseren Willen_ is correct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are correct that the accusative case is needed here, however *Willen* is not plural, it is accusative singular of *Wille*:

> Wir machen die Aufgabe wider unseren Willen.

Now, rules on when to use singular and when to use plural in German are not always clear-cut and they differ from English. In this case however, it is just that *Wille* is rarely used in plural at all. Indeed I had to look up whether it is even considered to have a plural (it is, according to [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Wille)).

You could probably try to argue that *wider unsere Willen* is also correct, but it would just sound so strange that I would have difficulty parsing it. If you said it, I might misunderstand it as *wider unsere Villen*. Which of course makes no sense. (That is the plural of *Villa* there.)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that in the accusative some nouns need an ending.

Comment: @user, isn’t German fun? ;) Others could tell you about declension classes now, I can just point you to a dictionary entry with a table: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wille

Comment: Yes, thanks again :)

Comment: The tricky part is *unseren* refers to a group so you think *Willen* must be plural, too. This isn't the case however, neither in German nor English. *So they waited for their departure.* – *Also warteten sie auf ihre Abfahrt.*

Comment: @Janka, this is true, but you could then start wondering whether they depart together or individually. However here, even if you think that their will is not collective, in German the plural of *Wille* is just awkward.